# Explain Egawa Electric field with reference to PIN diode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, diffusion, convection

By Egawa electric field I meant the flattening of electric field in the intrinsic field. And after that, when avalanche multiplication occurs, the dipping of electric field in the intrinsic region and the peaking of electric field in the intrinsic-n+ junction.

Comment: This seems to be covered well in his paper, Hideharu Egawa, IEEE Transactions on Electron Devices ED-13(11) 754-758 (1966). Could you clarify your issues with Egawa's explanation?

Comment: I read that paper before asking the question but I could not understand the explanation that was given

Comment: OK, what did you not understand, or where in the paper did you lose the thread? Edit the question to put that in. I can't read your mind and divine where to focus an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The egawa electric field occurs when charge flows out of the intrinsic region toward either junction. This will cause either an increase of decrease in field strength at the junction. If positive charge flows to the negative junction, negative charge will flow back toward the intrinsic region, thus making the negative junction more positive and pulling more negative charge toward it. This causes an exponentially increasing flow of negative charge toward the n+ junction in a process called avalanche multiplication.

A typical application of this would be a semiconductor or other electrical device where charge flows increase or decrease based on the state of junctions and intrinsic regions.